# Como paso $(this).valid() de jQuery a JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

como dice el titulo, quisiera saber como pasar el siguiente fragmento de codigo de jQuery a JS nativo. Alguno sabe?

Desde ya, gracias!

```
$(this).valid()
```

Edit: Dejo el bloque de codigo completo:

```
formSubmitConfirm: function() {
            document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        if ($(this).valid() && !miTest.forms.__submit && miTest.forms.__submitConfirm) {
            if (miTest.forms.__submitPreconfirm) {
            miTest.forms.__submitPreconfirm();
          }
          miTest.forms.confirm(miTest.messages.msg_confirmsubmit_title, miTest.messages
            .msg_comfirmsubmit_message, miTest.forms.formSubmit);
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    },
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace el método `.valid()`? ¿Se debe hacer algo antes de ejecutarlo? Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/519368/edit) para agregar más detalles, tanto de lo que hace ese método como de la forma en que lo ejecutas.

Comment: Editado, colega!

Comment: imagino que valid() debe validar el formulario.  Puedes usar e.target (el evento que dispara el listener) en vez de this